# Why does this not always have a return statement

Tags: java, matrix, return

```
private static BigInteger[] matrixPow(BigInteger[] matrix, int n){
    if(n==0){
        BigInteger[] result = {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE};   
    }
    else{
        BigInteger[] partial = matrixPow(matrix, n/2);
        BigInteger[] result = matrixMultiply(partial, partial);
        if(n%2 == 1){
            result = matrixMultiply(result,matrix);
        }
            return result;
    }

}
```

is the code that i have so far but the compiler says it doesnt always return, but its in a else statement what would i have to change

Comment: Your method doesn't return anything if `n` is 0.

Comment: I understand that that looks horrible to look at so heres a image of it
http://puu.sh/fPOhL/89561438e5.png

Comment: if n == 0 it returns the identity matrix

Comment: I fixed your formatting before you posted that. If every line in your code block starts with at least 4 spaces (or a tab), then Stack Overflow formats it as code.

Comment: No, if n == 0 your code assigns the identity matrix to a local variable, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks on a side question do you think that this is properly representing repeated squaring through recursion.

Answer (score 4):

You should move the `return result` up one scope.

```
private static BigInteger[] matrixPow(BigInteger[] matrix, int n){
    BigInteger[] result;
    if(n==0) {
        result = {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE};   
    } else {
        BigInteger[] partial = matrixPow(matrix, n/2);
        result = matrixMultiply(partial, partial);
        if(n%2 == 1) {
            result = matrixMultiply(result,matrix);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The underlying problem here is that your formatting, i.e. indentation is off, which makes it hard to see, where the scopes begin and end.

Answer (score 1):

The return is encapsulated in the `else` block.

You don't have a return in the `if` part of the `if else` block so when if it reached the `if` block, it won't return anything, hence the error.

Comment: @Thorx99 Additionally, you'll need to declare the variable `result` before the if-statement, otherwise scoping rules will make it invisible outside.